# Error : Cmake can't generate openCV

Tags: opencv, cmake, codeblocks

I am trying to instal opencv C++ with codeBlocks in Windows 8 by following this http://kevinhughes.ca/tutorials/opencv-install-on-windows-with-codeblocks-and-mingw/
 but I am blocked in step 4.when I try to generate Cmake I have this Error :

```
CMake Error: CMake was unable to find a build program corresponding to "MinGW Makefiles".  CMAKE_MAKE_PROGRAM is not set.  You probably need to select a different build tool.
CMake Error: CMake was unable to find a build program corresponding to "MinGW Makefiles".  CMAKE_MAKE_PROGRAM is not set.  You probably need to select a different build tool.
CMake Error: Error required internal CMake variable not set, cmake may be not be built correctly.
Missing variable is:
CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER_ENV_VAR
CMake Error: Error required internal CMake variable not set, cmake may be not be built correctly.
Missing variable is:
CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER
CMake Error: Could not find cmake module file: C:/MinGW/CMakeFiles/3.3.0-rc1/CMakeCXXCompiler.cmake
CMake Error: Error required internal CMake variable not set, cmake may be not be built correctly.
Missing variable is:
CMAKE_C_COMPILER_ENV_VAR
CMake Error: Error required internal CMake variable not set, cmake may be not be built correctly.
Missing variable is:
CMAKE_C_COMPILER
CMake Error: Could not find cmake module file: C:/MinGW/CMakeFiles/3.3.0-rc1/CMakeCCompiler.cmake
CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:63 (project):
  No CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER could be found.

  Tell CMake where to find the compiler by setting the CMake cache entry
  CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER to the full path to the compiler, or to the compiler
  name if it is in the PATH.


CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:63 (project):
  No CMAKE_C_COMPILER could be found.

  Tell CMake where to find the compiler by setting the CMake cache entry
  CMAKE_C_COMPILER to the full path to the compiler, or to the compiler name
  if it is in the PATH.


CMake Error: CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER not set, after EnableLanguage
CMake Error: CMAKE_C_COMPILER not set, after EnableLanguage
Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just do the obvious thing, and specify your c, c++ compiler and the make tool in question:

cmake -G "MinGW Makefiles" -DCMAKE_MAKE_PROGRAM="D:/Programme/MinGW/bin/mingw32-make.exe" -DCMAKE_CXX_COMPILER="D:/Programme/MinGW/bin/mingw32-g++.exe" -DCMAKE_C_COMPILER="D:/Programme/MinGW/bin/mingw32-gcc.exe" -DWITH_IPP=OFF ..

(ofc. your path will vary, but i hope, you get the idea)

((if you read between the lines - the opencv devs seem to be totally pissed off by having to maintain mingw pecularities, support for that seems to be on the demise))

Comment: thank you ,the problem is solved, it was that I had not " mingw32-make.exe  "so after your response I install it in my ordinateur and now it work